# New map in excel office 365 with vba. The code goes faster then the new map is synchronised to the cloud. Is there a way to solve this?

Tags: excel, vba, maps, cloud, office365

In excel office 365 working in the cloud there is a problem making new maps and saving an new file to that map. The new map is not ready synchronised to the cloud so the file saving gives an error. I can´t find the right error handling or maybe the best way to go over this new problem. I save on the user map link of onedrive and I thougt it was local but doesnt work.

Comment: `application.wait`?

Comment: or [`application.doevents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Something like that but I don´t know the code of application.wait or doevents. I ´ll try it, but waiting for what, how can vba know the map is synchronised to the cloud?